# Is my magnetometer calibrated correctly?

Tags: microcontroller, magnetics, imu, calibration, magnetometer

I am calibrating the AK8963 on the MPU9250. The first plot shows original mag readings and the last plot shows readings corrected for soft and hard bias. I am following the guidance of Kris Winer: https://github.com/kriswiner/MPU6050/wiki/Simple-and-Effective-Magnetometer-Calibration.

Do these plots look good enough or are they too flat? Is there a conventional metric to test for this. I was thinking of just plotting a perfect circle and calculating how well it fits.

each axis is in Microtesla

[image: original]

[image: hard iron corrected]

[image: Soft & Hard iron corrected]

Comment: Two problems. All three plots need scales in terms that someone answering might be able to determine the accuracy. At the moment they might be spectral images of a distant planet. The 2nd problem is that all three plots should have the same X and Y ranges.

Comment: Ah yes your right! I didn't even notice the different axis thanks for clarifying